# Twitter Bootstrap - Responsive Image & Carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, carousel

I am using the latest version of the twitter bootstrap.

I am also using the bootstrap-responsive.css.

I wish to have an image (As a picture frame), and a carousel (one provided with the bootstrap) within the center of such image. However i wish for them to be responsively resized.

The typical way I would have done this is, to make the carousel have position:relative, and simple overlap onto the image. But with the active resizing this results in problems.

Quite new to the whole media queries thing with css, any ideas of how this can be achieved?

Comment: Have you googled "responsive carousel"?

Comment: yes, the carousel is responsive. im just asking whats the best technique to have a carousel over an image with both resizing on response. e.g. a picture of a laptop, with a carousel in the 'laptop screen' of such picture. Where both responsively resize based on the @media queries

Answer (score 0):

What I did to make a site using bootstrap's carousel is...

```
<div id = "myCarousel" class = "carousel slide">
      <div class = "carousel-inner">
            <!--each slide goes here-->
            <div class = "item active">
                  <img src = "your image here..." class = "img-responsive">
            </div><!--end itemactive-->
            <div class = "item">
                  <img src = "your image here..." class = "img-responsive">
            </div><!--end itemactive-->
            <!--etc-->
      </div><!--end carousel-inner-->
</div><!--end carouselslide-->
```

Then in the CSS, I would have

```
#myCarousel
{
     background-image:url(your background image path here);
}

#myCarousel.carousel-inner
{
     width: 80%; /*carousel width size here - my example will use 80%, if you want the carousel to fill entire screen, then just remove this width element.*/
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     /*These two margins are to center the carousel if you set a smaller width. :) */
}
```

I used the bootstrap.min.css by the way.